# How do I find "prototype" values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I use the following function to detect values that belonged to an object's *constructor* instead of the object itself.

```
function isAPrototypeValue(object, key ) {
  return !(object.constructor && object.constructor.prototype[key]);
}
```

this would work as follows:

```
Array.prototype.base_value = 'base'
var array = new Array;
array.custom_value = 'custom'
alert( isAPrototypeValue( array, 'base_value' ) ) // true
alert( isAPrototypeValue( array, 'custom_value' ) ) // false
```

***But*** when I started to use inheritance:

```
function Base() {
  return this
};
Base.prototype.base_value = 'base';

function FirstSub() {
  return this
};
FirstSub.prototype = new Base();
FirstSub.prototype.first_value = 'first';

function SubB () {
  return this
};
SecondSub.prototype = new FirstSub();
SecondSub.prototype.second_value = 'second';

result = new SecondSub();
```

and I called

```
alert( result.constructor )
```

I would get **Base** instead of the expected **SecondSub**, which itself is not a big problem, But...

if I extended **result** like this:

```
result.custom_value = 'custom'
result.another_value = 'another'
```

I would have expected to be able to distinguish between values that belong to **result** or values that belong to **SecondSub, FirstSub and Base**;

eg.

```
alert( isAPrototypeValue( result, 'custom_value' ) ) // false ( as expected )
alert( isAPrototypeValue( result, 'base_value' ) ) // true ( as expected )
alert( isAPrototypeValue( result, 'first_value' ) ) // true extend, but it is false
alert( isAPrototypeValue( result, 'second_value' ) ) // true extend, but it is false
```

How can I change **isAPrototypeValue** to churn out the expected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might want to review Douglas Crockford's writing on inheritance in JavaScript. He has some in his book [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/), and some in his lectures on YUI Theater <http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/>. For distinguishing objects properties from those of the objects from which they are derived, see the [`hasOwnProperty()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). Crockford seems to argue that using classical inheritance in JavaScript is possible, but not the best way to go about exploiting the languages capabilities. Perhaps this will give you ideas on how to go about addressing what you're trying to accomplish. Best of luck regardless!

Crockford on Inheritance:

- [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html)
- [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)